# BlazeMeter hold-for option reduces concurrency too early

Tags: load-testing, blazemeter

For this BlazeMeter (BM) load test the number of virtual users (VU) is not held for the configured and expected duration of 20 minutes. The defined concurrency/number VU's reaches its peak of 5000 VU at 09:14 but begins to drop threads around 09:20.

The combined test duration is correct of ramp-up (2 minutes) + hold-for (20 minutes) but BM only holds the concurrency at the expected level for about 6-8 minutes (not 20 minutes as configured).

Do you know why BM might drop the VU's earlier than requested? I have included the Taurus configuration below (scenario details like request URL's are redacted).

[image: BlazeMeter load graph]

[taurus.yml]

```
---
aggregator: aggregator
execution:
- concurrency: 5000
  executor: jmeter
  hold-for: 20m
  locations:
    ap-northeast-1: 1
    ap-south-1: 1
    eu-central-1: 1
    eu-west-1: 1
    sa-east-1: 1
    us-east-1: 1
  ramp-up: 2m
  scenario: myscenario
local-bzt-version: 1.16.3
modules:
  cloud:
    account-id: '[CUT]'
    default-location: us-central1-a
    detach: true
    project-id: '[CUT]'
    test: [CUT]
    workspace-id: '[CUT]'
  consolidator:
    percentiles:
    - 0.0
    - 50.0
    - 90.0
    - 95.0
    - 99.0
    - 99.9
    - 100.0
  jmeter:
    plugins:
    - jpgc-casutg
    - jpgc-dummy
    - jpgc-ffw
    - jpgc-fifo
    - jpgc-functions
    - jpgc-json
    - jpgc-perfmon
    - jpgc-prmctl
    - jpgc-tst
    properties:
      jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush: 'true'
      jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time: 'true'
      jmeterengine.force.system.exit: 'true'
      summariser.name: ''
reporting:
- module: final-stats
- module: console
- module: final-stats
scenarios:
  myscenario:
  [CUT (default-address, some headers, list of request URL's)]    
schema: https://json.schemastore.org/taurus.json
services:
- local:
  - metrics:
    - cpu
    - mem
    - bytes-sent
    - bytes-recv
    - disk-read
    - disk-write
    - disk-space
    - engine-loop
    - conn-all
  module: monitoring
settings:
  default-executor: jmeter
  env:
    OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY: 'YES'
    TAURUS_ARTIFACTS_DIR: [CUT]
```

[bzt.log - Module config: jmeter]

```
{
'class': 'bzt.modules.jmeter.JMeterExecutor',
'protocol-handlers': {
    'http': 'bzt.jmx.http.HTTPProtocolHandler',
    'mqtt': 'bzt.jmx.mqtt.MQTTProtocolHandler'
},
'plugins': ['jpgc-casutg', 'jpgc-dummy', 'jpgc-ffw', 'jpgc-fifo', 'jpgc-functions', 'jpgc-json', 'jpgc-perfmon', 'jpgc-prmctl', 'jpgc-tst'],
'properties': {
    'jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush': 'true',
    'jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time': 'true',
    'jmeterengine.force.system.exit': 'true',
    'summariser.name': ''
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know because you have `[CUT]` few quite important parts of the configuration file.

I can think of the following possible reasons:

1. [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) with `Stop thread on EOF` set to `True`
2. [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler with action to `Stop` the `Current Thread`
3. A [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) which conditionally stops the thread

So check your test plan and ensure that none of the above listed options is your case.

In addition you might want to check the [Artifacts Directory](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ArtifactsDir/) and check `jmeter.log`, `jmeter.err` and `jmeter.out` files as well az `bzt.log` file.

And last but not the least as a BlazeMeter customer you can reach out to [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket), they are supposed to know the product much better than random people from the internet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. From the scenarios I have cut a single scenario consisting of a default-address, some headers and a list of requests URL's. I can't find an explicit option in the taurus config that should trigger the reasons as you've mentioned but I will try to grab relevant sections from the log files as you mentioned and update the question.